# How to provide multilingual content in MVC architecture

Tags: php, mysql

I try to design multilingual site. In my view files I put some variables that depends on language have different content. I have a function that parsing view file and put variables in array. Than I connect to DB and get content. Originally, question was about optimize this query to get content. But, maybe, whole approach was wrong?
Here is DB tables:

```
FIELDS
languages_short_name, char(3),    PRI
variable,             varchar(20),PRI
content,              longtext

LANGUAGES
short_name,           char(3),    PRI
name,                 varchar(20)
```

Here is the query:

```
    $subquery = 'Select \'' . 
    implode('\' as variable union Select \'', $var_array) . '\'';

    $query = sprintf( "Select tmp.variable, 
    if(fields.content is NULL , '%s', fields.content) as content FROM  fields
    RIGHT JOIN (%s) tmp
    ON tmp.variable = fields.variable 
    AND fields.languages_short_name = '%s'", 'not defined', $subquery, $lang );
```

Comment: This question would be better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I doubt there is a "less clumsy" way to do such thing. Reason is that you try to mix data from a completely separate level, with a completely different semantic. There should be no elegant way to do that, since it include a high risk and is against all ideas of writing software that can be maintained and is reusable.

Comment: You likely wouldn't want to use the database for this. You would want to re-index your array so that the data (column/key) you are joining on is a key. This allows you easy lookup access to the data. Then query your table without the join. As you loop over that result, you can lookup the data in the array by key from the column in the query. It seems like I didn't do a good job explaining, but without some sample data, that is hard to do.

Comment: This _could_ be a good question for Code Review, but you would need to add some background information for us to understand what you are trying to do. Tell us about your schema, provide some sample data, example parameters and results.

Comment: Thanks guys. I add some background.